# Location Game tile texturing

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, google-maps, unity-game-engine

I have the below code as a GPS controller and in Unity my map tiles are texturing fine... however, when I run in Xcode I get red question marks on all tiles. Is there something I'm not seeing here?

Have checked in Xcode debugger and my location coordinates are being found correctly but just not showing on tiles

Many thanks

```
{
    RoadMap,
    Satellite,
    Terrain,
    Hybrid
}

private const string GOOGLE_MAPS_URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap";

public int zoomLevel = 1;
public MapType mapType = MapType.RoadMap;
public int size = 640;
public bool doubleResolution = true;

public GPSLocationService gpsLocationService;

public MapLocation worldCenterLocation;
public MapLocation tileCenterLocation;

public Vector2 TileOffset;
public Vector2 TopLeftCorner;
public Vector2 BottomRightCorner;

private double lastGPSUpdate;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    RefreshMapTile ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (gpsLocationService != null &&
        gpsLocationService.IsServiceStarted && 
        lastGPSUpdate < gpsLocationService.Timestamp)
    {
        lastGPSUpdate = gpsLocationService.Timestamp;
        worldCenterLocation.Latitude = gpsLocationService.Latitude;
        worldCenterLocation.Longitude = gpsLocationService.Longitude;
        print("GoogleMapTile refreshing map texture");
        RefreshMapTile();
    }
}

public void RefreshMapTile() {

    StartCoroutine(_RefreshMapTile());
}

IEnumerator _RefreshMapTile ()
{            
    tileCenterLocation.Latitude = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLatByPixels(worldCenterLocation.Latitude, (int)(size * 1 * TileOffset.y), zoomLevel);
    tileCenterLocation.Longitude = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLonByPixels(worldCenterLocation.Longitude, (int)(size * 1 * TileOffset.x), zoomLevel);

    var url = GOOGLE_MAPS_URL;
    var queryString = "";

    queryString += "center=" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0},{1}", tileCenterLocation.Latitude, tileCenterLocation.Longitude));
    queryString += "&zoom=" + zoomLevel.ToString ();
    queryString += "&size=" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0}x{0}", size));
    queryString += "&scale=" + (doubleResolution ? "2" : "1");
    queryString += "&maptype=" + mapType.ToString ().ToLower ();
    queryString += "&format=" + "png";

    //styles
    queryString += "&style=element:geometry|invert_lightness:true|weight:3.1|hue:0x00ffd5";
    queryString += "&style=element:labels|visibility:off";

    var usingSensor = false;
```

if MOBILE_INPUT

```
    usingSensor = Input.location.isEnabledByUser && Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Running;
```

endif

```
    queryString += "&sensor=" + (usingSensor ? "true" : "false");

    //set map bounds rect
    TopLeftCorner.x = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLonByPixels(tileCenterLocation.Longitude, -size, zoomLevel);
    TopLeftCorner.y = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLatByPixels(tileCenterLocation.Latitude, size, zoomLevel);

    BottomRightCorner.x = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLonByPixels(tileCenterLocation.Longitude, size, zoomLevel);
    BottomRightCorner.y = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLatByPixels(tileCenterLocation.Latitude, -size, zoomLevel);

    print(string.Format("Tile {0}x{1} requested with {2}", TileOffset.x, TileOffset.y, queryString));

    var req = new WWW(url + "?" + queryString);
    //var req = new WWW("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=50.917316,-114.080923&zoom=17&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=roadmap&style=feature:landscape.man_made|visibility:on|invert_lightness:true");
    yield return req;
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = req.texture;
    print(string.Format("Tile {0}x{1} textured", TileOffset.x, TileOffset.y));
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure you have Internet access when running in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks but that isn't the issue. I have access